# Count number of lines in a nested for loop

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:
[image]

each text look like this:
"ALL TEXT IS RELEVANT\r\n\r\nGood morning, and welcome to the Origin Agritech Limited's Fiscal 2016 Earnings Conference Call. All participants will be in listen-only mode. \r\n\r\nI would now like to turn the conference over to Bill Zima. Mr. Zima, Please go ahead.\r\n\r\nThank you, operator. Hello, everyone, and thank you for joining us on today's call. Origin Agritech announced its full year 2016 financial results earlier today. Details about this announcement can be found on the company's website.\r\n\r\nToday, you will hear from Origin's Chief Executive Officer, Dr. Bill Niebur, who'll address company developments and strategies, followed by the company's Chief Financial Officer, Mr. Shashank Aurora, who will review fiscal 2016 financial results. Dr. Niebur will then conclude the company's remarks by providing commentary on the 2017 business outlook, which will be followed by a question-and-answer session.\r\n\r\nBefore we begin, I would like to remind you of our Safe Harbor statement. Our conference call may include forward-looking statements made under the Safe Harbor provisions of the Private Securities Litigation Reform Act of 1995. Although, we believe that the expectations reflected in our forward-looking statements are reasonable as of today, those statements are subject to risks and uncertainties that could cause actual results to differ dramatically from those projected. There can be no assurance that those expectations will prove to be correct...

I want to count the number of lines in each article_text and use it for computation:

I thought of doing something like this:

```
def doc_sentiment (dataframe):
    score_dict={}
    scores=[]
    number_of_sent=0
    for call in dataframe.article_text:
        for sentence in split_into_sentences(call):
            number_of_sent+=1
            vs=sia.polarity_scores(sentence)
            score_dict.update({sentence: vs['compound']})
            score=sum(score_dict.values())/number_of_sent
```

This, however, doesn't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by this also counts the number of articles? Are you talking about how the number of lines is the total spread across all the articles and not a number per article?

Comment: What dataframe is it? `pandas` I assume?

Comment: Yes. this is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: could you provide at least one example of a full article text  from one of your records? I believe that might get  you more accurate answers to your case as they could test their code on that sample

Comment: did it, and also added some code lines. Thanks.

Comment: _This, however, doesn't work._ What happens instead?

Answer (score 2):

so basically you are asking to count with 1 less at each iteration from your inner`for` loop:

```
number_of_sent=0
for call in dataframe.article_text:
    for sentence in split_into_sentences(call):
        number_of_sent+=1

    number_of_sent -= 1
```